# Can't deploy global value set using SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-error

I've been trying to deploy one single global value set to a test scratch org as I get comfortable with SFDX but I cannot seem to get it to work.

This is the command I'm using:

`sfdx force:source:deploy -u stagingTest -p "./globalValueSets/Time_Zones.globalValueSet"`

The error I keep getting is:

`Error  Time_Zones  An object 'Time_Zones' of type GlobalValueSet was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory`

If I try and use force:source:push instead I get

`Expected file at path: ../../../../globalValueSets\Time_Zones.globalValueSet-meta.xml`

This is the content of `./globalValueSets/Time_Zones.globalValueSet` (Retrieved with Illuminated Cloud from a Sandbox):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GlobalValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customValue>
        <fullName>ACST</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>ACST</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>BST</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>BST</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>CEST</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>CEST</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>CST</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>CST</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>EST</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>EST</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>GMT</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>GMT</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>Hawaiian</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Hawaiian</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>MT</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>MT</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>PST</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>PST</label>
    </customValue>
    <masterLabel>Time Zones</masterLabel>
    <sorted>false</sorted>
```

And here is the entry in my package.xml:

```
  <types>
    <members>Days_of_the_week</members>
    <members>Default_Set_Letter</members>
    <members>Default_Set_Number</members>
    <members>Default_Set_Type</members>
    <members>Demographic_Type</members>
    <members>Dropped_Trainee_Reason</members>
    <members>Eligibility_Options</members>
    <members>Equipment_Condition</members>
    <members>Equipment_Distributors</members>
    <members>Equipment_Types</members>
    <members>Host_Training_Requirements</members>
    <members>Months_of_Year</members>
    <members>New_Locations_Email_Status</members>
    <members>New_Locations_Sales_Status</members>
    <members>Open_Position_Stages</members>
    <members>Organization_Wide_Emails</members>
    <members>Primary_Churn_Reason_Non_Hosted_Show</members>
    <members>Recruiters</members>
    <members>Refund_Status</members>
    <members>Sales_Bonus_Types</members>
    <members>Secondary_Recruiters</members>
    <members>Show_Services</members>
    <members>Show_Times</members>
    <members>Show_Types</members>
    <members>Time_Zones</members>
    <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
  </types>
```

I don't know why it's expecting a zipped directory of some sort. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "zipped directory" thing is just how deployments happen. The contents of whatever directory you set as the path are converted in to a zip file before being uploaded. The system is complaining because it is expecting a file called `Time_Zones.globalValueSet-meta.xml`. Make sure you're not missing the bit at the end, that's important.

Comment: Thanks, all I needed to do was add -meta.xml to the file names